# Is it possible to create dynamic tabs in Kendo Angular Tabstrip?

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I want to create tabstrip and append inside tab when i click from left menu. I created all my components and use this components as an Content of dynamic tabs.

Is it possible with kendo Angular Tabstrip Layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can using the built-in ngFor to have the component's template loop over a collection variable defined on the component to dynamically show the tabs.

Take a look at this example. If you were to add or remove from the `tabs` variable, it will dynamically be reflected in the DOM.

Component's Template:

```html
<kendo-tabstrip>
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let first = first" [title]="tab.header" [selected]="first">
    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
      <div class="content">
        <img [src]="tab.body.image" />
        <h2>{{ tab.body.degrees }}<span>ºC</span></h2>
        <span>{{ tab.body.description }}</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

Variable Declared in Component:

```javascript
tabs = [
  {
    header: 'Paris',
    body: {
      image:
        'https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/rainy.png',
      degrees: '17',
      description: 'Rainy weather in Paris.',
    },
  },
  {
    header: 'New York City',
    body: {
      image:
        'https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/cloudy.png',
      degrees: '19',
      description: 'Cloudy weather in New York City.',
    },
  },
  {
    header: 'Tallinn',
    body: {
      image:
        'https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/sunny.png',
      degrees: '23',
      description: 'Sunny weather in Tallinn.',
    },
  },
  {
    header: 'London',
    body: {
      image:
        'https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/rainy.png',
      degrees: '16',
      description: 'Rainy weather in London.',
    },
  },
];
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iwwkxv

Comment: Thanks @David . I understand this but what i want a bit different.. Think about cities are menu list and i have no any selected tabs when i click one item in list like i clicked Paris. Paris Tab create and i can do my job there too. Is this possible?

Comment: @saulyasar - So using my example, the `tabs` variable would start off empty and when you click on Paris it would push a new object to the array.

Comment: can you do it please?

Comment: `this.tabs.push({ header: 'paris', body: { image: 'https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/layout/assets/tabstrip/rainy.png', degrees:'17', description: 'Rainy weather in Paris.' } })` is what I was suggesting, you will need to modify it to fix exactly what you want.